# Value of setting variable keeps changing

Tags: swift, uisegmentedcontrol, option-type

I'm trying to create a multi language  app. There's a UISegmented control bar with 3 segments for three languages. I've created the language variable that will hold the value (english - 0, cantonese - 1, mandarin - 2). My problem is that in the simulator when I change the selected segment control, the language variable will change randomly even though each segment should change the variable to a specific variable.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
class About: UIViewController {

var language: Int?
@IBOutlet weak var selectLanguage: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var whatIsiEd: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

func checkLanguage() -> Int? {
    return language
}

@IBAction func setLanguage(sender: AnyObject) {
    if self.selectLanguage.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        println("Language is set to English - \(language) - \(self.selectLanguage.selectedSegmentIndex)")
        language = 0
    } else if self.selectLanguage.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        println("Language is set to Traditional Chinese - \(language) - \(self.selectLanguage.selectedSegmentIndex)")
        language = 1
    } else if self.selectLanguage.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {
        println("Language is set to Simplified Chinese - \(language) - \(self.selectLanguage.selectedSegmentIndex)")
        language = 2
    }
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

When I use the simulator by default the segment controller is set to English (segment 0). Then I change to segment 1, then 2, then back to 1 and finally 0. The log reports the following:

Language is set to Traditional Chinese - nil - 1
Language is set to Simplified Chinese - Optional(1) - 2
Language is set to Traditional Chinese - Optional(2) - 1
Language is set to English - Optional(1) - 0

Comment: Where are you seeing the incorrect `language` value? Is it when you reset the simulator? Does it initial print the correct language when you click a new segmented index?

Comment: I see it when I launch the simulator. For example,Language is set to Traditional Chinese - nil - 1
Language is set to English - Optional(1) - 0
Language is set to Traditional Chinese - Optional(0) - 1
Language is set to Simplified Chinese - Optional(1) - 2

Comment: Sorry having a hard time understanding your comment. Update your question so you can better format it. Also, you are not storing `langauge` anywhere persistent so upon simulator relaunch it will go back to the default, unless you are doing this somewhere else.

Comment: Hi Firo, thanks for trying to help me with this. I've written an app before doing the same thing in Objective-C, but I'm still kind of inexperienced with programming. I edited the post to include the log report and procedure I was using.

Comment: I actually do not understand where the issue is. Things are working exactly as expected. One thing that may be confusing you, is that you are performing the print before setting the language, so the `language` that is printed is the previous language. Try swapping the assignment and printing lines and see if that makes sense.

Comment: Hi Firo, you're absolutely right. That was a big mistake on my part. Thanks for pointing it out to me

Comment: I created an answer below based on what we talked about here. Glad you got it sorted out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As found from the comments. You were just logging the `language` before assigning it the correct value. In this case if you just swap the assignment of `language` and the print statement you should be good:

```
@IBAction func setLanguage(sender: AnyObject) {
    if self.selectLanguage.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        // Assignment
        language = 0
        // Then print. Now your result will be correct.
        println("Language is set to English - \(language) - \(self.selectLanguage.selectedSegmentIndex)")
    } else if ...
}
```